# How to change img src added by on click function?

Tags: javascript, image, src

I would like to change variable `var ajax_loader = jQuery('<img class="fl-spinner" width="16" heigth="16" src="' + fl_mc_settings.fl_spinner + '" />');` of externally added _.js, that I can't change, remove etc.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on("click", ".fl_click_switcher a", fl_switch_currency_handler)
});
var fl_switch_currency_handler = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (jQuery(this).is(":disabled") || jQuery(this).parent().hasClass("fl-cs-active-currency") || jQuery(this).hasClass("fl-cs-active-currency")) {
        return false
    } else {
        jQuery(this).off(event)
    }
    fl_load_currency(jQuery(this).attr("rel"))
};
function fl_load_currency(currency, force_switch) {
    var ajax_loader = jQuery('<img class="fl-spinner" width="16" heigth="16" src="' + fl_mc_settings.fl_spinner + '" />');
    jQuery(".fl_click_switcher").append(ajax_loader);
    if (typeof force_switch === "undefined")
        force_switch = 0;
    jQuery.ajax({.........
```

- Is there way, to override above mentioned variable, with rest of original functions untouched?
- or: How override variable html output - in case that output is added after onclick function?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution must be to add `fl_mc_settings.fl_spinner = "new-image.jpg";` to your script (make sure it loads after the spinner js)

With it one simply override the image being used as the *spinner*

---

E.g.

```
<script src="path-to-spinner.js"></script>
<script>
    fl_mc_settings.fl_spinner = "new-image.jpg";
</script>
```

---

Updated based on a comment

As the image source is injected into a HTML fragment, here is a trick using an `img`'s `onload` event.

What it does is to also inject `onload="wrap_img(this);"` into the `img` markup, and when the image gets inserted, and the image been loaded, the event fires, and one can then, here done with jQuery's `.wrap()` method, wrap the image in e.g. a `div`.

```js
var fl_spinner = 'http://placehold.it/200x100/" onload="wrap_img(this);"';
var ajax_loader = '<img class="fl-spinner" width="160" heigth="160" src="' + fl_spinner + '" />';

function wrap_img(img) {
  $(img).wrap( "<div class='spinner_wrapper'></div>" );
}

document.body.innerHTML = ajax_loader;
```

```css
.spinner_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

And in your case it could look something like this

```
<script src="path-to-spinner.js"></script>
<script>
    fl_mc_settings.fl_spinner = 'new-image.jpg" onload="wrap_img(this);"';

    function wrap_img(img) {
      jQuery(img).wrap( "<div class='spinner_wrapper'></div>" );
    }
</script>
<style>
    .spinner_wrapper {
      display: inline-block;
      background: red;
      padding: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks you! It is working. Additionally... is there way to change whole html output? `<img class="fl-spinner" width="16" heigth="16" src="' + fl_mc_settings.fl_spinner + '" />`  or embed <img> in <div> with class?

Comment: @Gore Then you most likely need to replace the entire `function fl_load_currency(currency, force_switch) {...}` function ... just add a new one in the same way I suggested in my answer and check if it works

Comment: Did you mean copy whole function from original source, place it to new file loaded after original and modify it?

Comment: @Gore Yes, I meant that ... but I updated with a trick that might be enough